# Can Firefox display JP2 images?

Tags: html, css, image, file, web

I have recently converted every image on my website to JP2 to decrease file size while still having transparency.

On Safari everything works great, but Firefox does not display the JP2 images, however it does display PNGs.

Is JP2 unsupported in Firefox?

Comment: Yes it is not supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=jp2

Comment: It seems to be related with software patents on mathematical compression techniques. No luck..

Comment: Also, wondering why you chose this format specifically, instead of, for example, .png..

Comment: @Kaddath Because it is based on JPG, so the file size is much smaller and it supports Alpha.

Comment: @Kaddath a patent problem? Well, NO MORE since 2019. Look at the last sentence of the paragraph "Legal status" in the wiki page of JPEG 2000. Now we are just facing to "not widely supported in web browsers".

Comment: This may or may not be fair. However, the webp format (from Google) seems to have taken over the web as the next generation format of choice. Note that Safari 14 does support webp. By contrast, Chrome and Firefox do not support JP2. Note that JAI seems to have dropped JP2 support after supporting it for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JP2 images are not supported on Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpeg2000).

But you can use the [`<picture>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) element to provide multiple image formats so the browser can choose and display the supported image format:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="img/example.jp2" type="image/jp2"> <!-- format supported by safari -->
    <source srcset="img/example.webp" type="image/webp"> <!-- format supported on many browsers -->
    <source srcset="img/example.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> <!-- common supported format -->
    <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="example-alt-text"> <!-- default -->
</picture>
```

**Note:** An alternative to the JP2 format could be the WebP format:

- [Comparison WebP, JPEG, JP2/JPEG2000](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/c_study)
- [More about the WebP format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/)

Comment: i tried this code, and all the browsers revert to the default. how do I tell Safari to use the jp2? or any browser to use webp?

Comment: Why? It's a so good format, it's used almost everywhere under the hood, but never as a file format. (h265, pdf...)

Answer (score 2):

**(JP2)** Supported browser below:

Firefox: Not supported.

Chrome: Not supported.

Safari: Supported.

You can also check this link:
`https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpeg2000`